# Visual studio has suspended some advanced features to improve performance weirdness

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My dev environment is:

- VS2015 Ultimate Fully Patched
- Win10 64bit 32GB RAM
- Developing a WebForms application
- Resharper
- IIS Express

For the last couple of days VS has started popping up the following in the IDE:

[image]

The VS process is using around 1.2GB of memory and I have 16GB free. And then if I have run up the webforms application and am debugging (not at a break point, code is running) the next time I navigate in the application I get a YSOD of **Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.**

Clearly VS seems to think its process is struggling in terms of memory but as I still have 16GB free it isn't. Disabling R# has no effect.

Has anyone got any ideas on how to fix this? Or is anyone else experiencing anything similair?

Comment: It *is* struggling. Visual Studio is a 32-bit process which means it can see about 2GB. Although an OutOfMemoryException can be caused by many things, including memory fragmentation. If you have such issues, your code probably has some sever memory leak issues

Comment: I'm not sure if Visual Studio or your applicatoin is struggling. What Panagitois Kanavos said is not only true for visual studio but also for your application. As mentioned, you might have memory leaks. If not, you should consider compiling for 64-bit architecture (if that is an option).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos VS is LargeAddressAware, so it can use up to 4GB on 64Bit Windows.

Comment: @magicandre1981 and the runtime can still suffer from memory fragmentation. If the code generates a lot of large temporary objects, there may not be a single contiguous block of memory to use for a new object. Creating a list of 1M items by adding one item at a time will create a *lot* of temporary buffers as the list grows by reallocating its internal buffer each time it reaches its limit.

Comment: @magicandre1981 also note that the OP mentions an YSOD. What actually throws is an ASP.NET application that's probably not Large Address Aware.

Comment: VS is running in its own process and the ASP.NET app is running in its own process. So memory leaks non withstanding in the ASP.NET app the two should be isolated from each other - VS should not be the one being affected. Unless I have this wrong something is going wrong inside VS to cause this. Now while it could be the debugger that is getting clobberred I am still struggling to see the link between ASP and VS in this happening.

Comment: @TheEdge the YSOD means the exception is thrown by the ASP.NET app. And 1.2GB while debugging is a *lot* of RAM. The debugger has to track all allocated objects so a leaky application will cause a lot of memory usage. In any case I'd profile the application *first* and look for leaks